# Drill Casting to date gives wrong values

Tags: sql, apache-drill, to-date

I have started using Drill date conversion function
and read [this link](https://drill.apache.org/docs/data-type-conversion/#to_date-syntax)

So i was trying to imlement `TO_DATE(<field>, <format>)`

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT  DRILL_TABLE_214.date_id ,
       (DRILL_TABLE_214.date_id / 100) dup_by_100,
       CAST((DRILL_TABLE_214.date_id / 100) as varchar)  dup_by_100_with_casting,
       to_date(CAST((DRILL_TABLE_214.date_id / 100) as varchar),'yyyymmdd') `DATE_DAY` ,
       clicks DRILL_TABLE_214_MES_CLICKS 
FROM
    s3.dss.`acc=123/run-num-id=214` DRILL_TABLE_214 
WHERE
    ( DRILL_TABLE_214.date_id >= 2017040100 AND DRILL_TABLE_214.date_id <= 2017063023 )
```

I was trying to figure out why Does Drill convert the month to January in the To date function - but its unclear .

can you help me verify why ?[image: Date conversion is invalid]

i also tried converting this value:

```
to_date('2017-03-13','yyyy-mm-dd')  xxxx ,
```

But i got:

```
2017-01-13T00:00:00.000+02:00
```

Anyone faced the same issue ?

Comment: shoud be MM for month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be MM for month not mm for minutes